# What is the RSpec syntax equivalent for assert (minitest)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial. I observe that he used minitest to run his tests. I use RSpec. Below is a line of code from the tutorial I want to replicate with RSpec

```
test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
  valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                     first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
  valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
    @user.email = valid_address
    assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
  end
end
```

This is how I will do this in with RSpec.

```
it "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
  valid_addresses = ["user@example.com", "USER@foo.COM", "A_US-ER@foo.bar.org",
                     "first.last@foo.jp", "alice+bob@baz.cn"]
  valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
    user.email = valid_address
    expect(@user.valid?).to be true, "#{valid_address.inspect} is not correct"
  end
end
```

However, I get Argument error when I run this test. It appears RSpec expects only one argument in test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSpec thinks that you're passing a single argument to the `to` method and two arguments to the `be` method, and hence it's giving you an error.  It's seeing your statement as:

```
expect(@user.valid?).to(be(true, "#{valid_address.inspect} is not correct"))
```

So, you can change your spec to be the following, and it should work:

```
expect(@user.valid?).to be(true), "#{valid_address.inspect} is not correct"
```

Here, RSpec is seeing two arguments being passed to the `to` method, which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error message you are getting. It looks like you have a typo. Should

```
user.email = valid_address
```

be

```
@user.email = valid address
```

You're providing 2 arguments and the expect statement takes one.

```
expect(@user.valid?).to be true
```

Comment: That's a typo @margo, ```user``` should be ```@user```. The error message is: ```ArgumentError:
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)```